# How do I measure the real height of a rendered string?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I’m trying to measure a string to be drawn. I have tried `sizeWithAttributes:`, but that doesn’t make a difference between different characters:

```
NSLog(@"A: %@", NSStringFromCGSize([@"." sizeWithAttributes:labelAttributes]));
NSLog(@"B: %@", NSStringFromCGSize([@"X" sizeWithAttributes:labelAttributes]));
A: {6, 23}
B: {12, 23}
```

Note that the reported height is the same for both characters. Is there a call that would honour the height difference between `.` and `X`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as "real height". Font metrics are a complex topic.

A string (consisting of characters) is converted to a bunch of glyphs. Those glyphs define what will be visible (rendered). This process involves endless subtleties that might change what you define as the "real height".

Examples:

- Some characters extend **very** far over the normal line height.
- Some (graphical) rendering options stretch out beyond the bounding box of all glyphs (like shadows or outlines).
- Font metrics contain a myriad of different values for what could be considered the bounding box of a character (or glyph).

[image: Zapfino Glyphs]

This image shows the string `"abc   f   123"` rendered using the font Zapfino (in TextEdit.app on a Mac). The f character is selected (green box). The visual character stretches far beyond of what the selection considers the bounding box.

The red text has a shadow applied to it. It's not easy to calculate the bounding box of this part of the text either.

Your case sounds like you consider a `"."` character to have a smaller size than a `"X"`. But has a space character a zero size then? It's really difficult to define the "real size" without exact knowledge of the use case. And even then there are often many undefined edge cases.

I had a use case where I wanted to convert strings to PNG images (stupid, I know). In that case the best option was to render the string into a large bitmap context and then search through the raw data bitplanes from the outside inwards until finding first non-transparent pixels.

Comment: By “real height” I meant the bounding box of the rendered glyphs. Which doesn’t always give expected or intuitive results (thank you for the great example), but would be usable enough for me. I guess I’ll have to try something else. Thank you!

Comment: @zoul It would be great if you could share your findings. Calculating the bounding box of all laid out glyphs of a string is complicated in itself. Since iOS now has the great `NSLayoutManager` API it might not be too difficult to do this and it might help others who have similar use cases.

Comment: I just want to align a word vertically inside a button, so I’m not going for a general case and my expected solution (probably involving some simple calculation based on hardcoded values or baseline manipulation) is not going to be very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Nikolai. I think the best you can do is to get smallest possible size like following.

```
self.myLabel.text = @".";
[self.myLabel setNeedsLayout];
[self.myLabel layoutIfNeeded];

NSLog(@"A: %@", NSStringFromCGSize([self.myLabel systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize]));

self.myLabel.text = @"X";
[self.myLabel setNeedsLayout];
[self.myLabel layoutIfNeeded];

NSLog(@"B: %@", NSStringFromCGSize([self.myLabel systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize]));

A: {5, 21}
B: {11, 21}
```

If you want the smallest possible size, pass UILayoutFittingCompressedSize; for the largest possible size, pass UILayoutFittingExpandedSize.